# I2C connection randomly dies with error 4

Tags: arduino, i2c, imu

I am trying to interface an ESP8266 microcontroller with an ICM-20948 IMU chip.

Using the reference code from Invensense, the internet and trial and error, I managed to configure the chip do do 9-axis sensor fusion using its internal compass and DMP.

I am using a mosfet(BSS138)-based level shifter and a linear voltage regulator to provide the ICM with its required 1.7V VCC / logic voltage.

For the first 5-30 seconds, everything works fine and I get perfect drift-corrected quaternions. However, the data stream then just apruptly stops and the call to `Wire.endTransmission()` fails with error 4 (which very helpfully means "other error")

Does anyone know what the reason for such behavior could be?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117871/discussion-on-question-by-twometer-i2c-connection-randomly-dies-with-error-4).